# Trying to to store values then use -1 to print the results, but the program close itself

Tags: c, visual-studio

This is an assignment that my teacher gave me, been trying to get it work for a few days now and can't find what causing the problem.

The code that I type works on a 2012 version of visual studio and when using a 2017 version, the code closes on itself when I enter -1 into the console and I can't get it to print the grades that I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int grades = 0;
int counter = 0;
int A = 0;
int B = 0;
int C = 0;
int D = 0;
int E = 0;

do
{
       counter++;
       printf("Please enter grade between 0 to 100 or -1 to quit:");
       scanf_s("%d", &grades);
       if (grades != -1 ){

        if (grades >= 90 && grades <= 100)
           A++;
       else if (grades >= 80 && grades <= 89)
           B++;
       else if (grades >= 70 && grades <= 79)
           C++;
       else if (grades >= 60 && grades <= 69)
           D++;          
       else if (grades >= 0 && grades <= 59)
           E++;
       else counter--;
       }
       else
           counter--;
       }
while (grades != -1);

       printf("Total Number of Grades = %d\n\n", counter);
       printf("Number of grade A: %d\n", A);
       printf("Number of grade B: %d\n", B);
       printf("Number of grade C: %d\n", C);
       printf("Number of grade D: %d\n", D);
       printf("Number of grade E: %d\n", E);

       return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "closes on itself"? Does the console window close? When starting console applications from Visual Studio, it adds a call to `pause` at the end, so you can see the output, maybe the newer version doesn't do that. Did you try calling your program in an externally started console?

Comment: Yes, the console window closes, instantly when I enter -1 so i can't see the output do you have any idea on what caused this.

Comment: I also tried starting the program without using visual studio. The results are the same.(Thou I am just guessing on what you mean by starting the console externally still new to this stuff.)

Answer (score 3):

To my understanding, the program does what you expect (printing the grades at the end), but you are unable to see the results beacause the program terminates and the windows closes. You can wait for a keypress at the end using the `getchar` function, which is explained [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Too keep the console window open in Visual Studio start the project with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> instead of just <kbd>F5</kbd>.